# Modify fulfillment.tracking_url variable?

Tags: shopify

As part of a Shopify app I'm building, I'd like to modify the `fulfillment.tracking_url` email variable.

Specifically, when a customer is emailed their tracking number, I want to change the tracking URL from the default carrier so that ALL tracking links are this format:

`http://example-store.myshopify.com/tools/track?n=1Z18E08VYW76416035`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently isn't possible, but it's something Shopify is thinking of making available. We will let you know once it's out via an upcoming Shopify Developer newsletter and over [@shopifyapi](http://twitter.com/shopifyapi).